# What is shunt regulator in comparison with voltage reference

Tags: voltage-reference, shunt

I know what is voltage reference but I am really confused about the difference between voltage reference and shunt regulator

for example TL431 can I use it as voltage reference ?

what is the applications for the shunt regulator anyway?

Comment: I wounder what is the benefit of the negative points system if it doesn't tell the user what is actually the negative part or the wrong part in the question or the answer!
they must force the user to add comment when giving negative feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between a regulator and a reference is that the accuracy of a device intended for use as a reference will be fairly good- usually +/-1% or better for tolerance and similarly good regulation and output noise level. Many regulators are only guaranteed to +/-5%, down to perhaps +/-1%. Regulators are usually designed to handle more current. Series voltage references almost always can sink as well as source current, whereas that is rare in voltage regulators.

There is a some overlap- it's quite possible to use (especially a lightly loaded) regulator as a reasonable reference, and you can certainly use a reference as a voltage regulator in some circumstances.

Most regulators are "series" type, as opposed to shunt type. A shunt voltage reference (or regulator) behaves like a very accurate Zener that requires a certain relatively high minimum current to properly regulate. For example, the cheapest variant of the LM431 requires an anode current of 1mA minimum.

Series regulators and voltage references have a minimum of 3 pins- an input, a ground, and an output. Series references are widely available, though they tend to be more expensive than shunt types. An example of a series reference would be an [ADR4550](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADR4520_4525_4530_4533_4540_4550.pdf). It can supply 5V at up to 10mA, which does not sound very impressive for a voltage regulator, but is accurate to +/-0.02% (+/-1mV) for the highest grade.

The [LM431](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm431.pdf) is the voltage reference used in many (probably most) isolated switching supplies such as PC power supplies- tied together with an optoisolator it allows closed-loop control of the output voltage. 
It could be used as a voltage regulator, similar to a zener diode, with similar limitations (plus a higher minimum anode current). Shunt supplies don't work so well when there is a lot of input voltage variation and especially when the minimum input voltage approaches the output voltage and output current is substantial. That's because the series resistor must be low enough to deliver the *maximum* load current plus the minimum regulator anode current with the minimum input voltage. So suppose your load could draw as much as 10mA @ 5V and minimum 1mA, and you want an input voltage of 6V-15V. The resistor can be no higher than (6V-5V)/0.011A (1mA for the LM431) = 90\$\Omega\$. In reality there are a couple other tolerances so suppose we make the resistor 82 ohms. Now when the input voltage is 15V, and the load current is 1mA, then the LM431 must conduct 121mA, which is above its rating, and dissipate 1.21W which is well above its capability, especially for an SMT SOT-23-5 type.

Comment: the thing that makes confuse for me is the word shunt actually

Comment: my head is now spinning 0.0

Comment: @muhammad, shunt or shunting is an action meaning to direct current somewhere, usually ground. A shunt regulator is just a type of voltage regulator that shunts excess current to ground to maintain a voltage. For them to do this they need a reference voltage. Their point is that sometimes the lines between a regulator and a reference can be blurred, as a regulator needs a reference but a reference isn't always a regulator.

Comment: ahhhhh, Now I do understand what is the use of the word shunt in the context and I believe that was the answer that I was waiting for from the beginning thank you very much for clarifying this for me

Comment: can you point me if possible to a place to read more about shunt regulators applications

Comment: They're generally part of a class known as linear regulators: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator

Answer (score 1):

A voltage reference has normally a fixed voltage and doesnt provide normally a very high current, however the distinctions are not allways that clear, as you exemplified, the tl431, it can be indeed used both as a voltage reference and as a regulator you just need to connect the ref pin to the output to use it as a voltage reference of the specified voltage, or you can use a voltage divider to set the output voltage which however you would not normally use that for a voltage reference because of the error it introduces but may be perfectly acceptable for a regulator if the current is enough, it must be noted though that the most accurate voltage references are normally useless as regulators because of the low current they withstand, an example of this would be the ADR130 which can only supply 4ma

Comment: your answer didn't explain what is shunt regulator!! it doesn't even has the word 'shunt'